# How to get a creation timestamp from the symfony cache entry?

Tags: php, caching, symfony

I am using Symfony to cache some files to my file system.

Currently I have a YAML file that is being decoded to a PHP array which I in turn store the the cache with the Symfony Caching component.

When my YAML file changes I need to re-cache it, even if it is already in cache. I need to get the modification time of the cached file (which holds the decoded YAML) and compare it to my YAML file.

If the modification time of my YAML file is newer, I need to re-cache.

How can I get the creation time of the cache entry though? I know Symfony has the creation time in the cache entry. So it has the data, I just am wondering if there is a clean way to get it. I know this because the entry looks like this:

```
1515867059
<CacheEntryName>
<SerializedData>
```

1515867059 being the unix timestamp when it was created.

Hopefully somebody can help me out.

**Edit:**
I guess it would also be helpful if I could get the absolute path to the cache entry. With that I could generate an `SplFileInfo` object and get the modification time from it like that.

Cheers.

Comment: Question: have you a deploy pipe or automated process? If so, when deploy new files, just recreate the cache and you'll be sure 100% that your informations will be correct. Of course, cache recreation could be done through cache warmers, so you don't need to worry about performance as it will be a single shot task done before application returns live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony cache currently does not have a way to deal with this. As a temporary solution I included the timestamp myself with an array:

```
$cached->set([
    'value' => $value,
    'timestamp' => time()
]);
```

Works for now.